# URLWithString returning nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

I have this code:

NSString *logsPath = [dataDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logs"];

Which returns:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA/Documents/Mobile Documents/Data/Logs
```

However, doing this:

```
NSURL *logsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logsPath];
```

returns a value of nil.

Any ideas as to why this might be?

Answer (score 7):

Try using `+fileURLWithPath:` instead.

Because `+URLWithString:` expects a protocol (e.g. http://, https://, file://), it cannot build a URL.

On the other hand, `+fileURLWithPath:` just takes the raw path, and automatically appends the file:// protocol to the path you supply.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSURL urlWithString:logsPath]` expects for the url to start with https:// or http://.  `[dataDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logs"];` returns a path and not a URL.  To fix this use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:logsPath]`.  This will add file:// to the beginning of the URL making it work.
Your full code will look like this:

```
NSString *logsPath = [dataDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logs"];
NSURL *logsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:logsPath];
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that spaces are illegal in URL paths. -fileURLWithPath: works because it URI encodes the space, not because it adds a scheme.

```
(lldb) po [NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo bar"]
nil
(lldb) po [NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo-bar"]
/foo-bar
(lldb) po [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/foo bar"]
file://localhost/foo%20bar
(lldb) po [NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo%20bar"]
/foo%20bar
```